# Extending classes and using traits for main class

Tags: php, oop

I'm building an api with php and I am not that familiar with extending classes or using traits. Currently I'm using traits to better structure my main `API` class.

See below for the current way of working. I was wondering if I could create a class inside the `API` class. One which is for example responsible for the `webhook` methods. This needs to have access to all methods on both router and api for the current instance.

**Example**

When people access the api on `/v1/{method}/{verb}/{args}`

```
if (!array_key_exists('HTTP_ORIGIN', $_SERVER)) {
    $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'] = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
}

try {
    $API = new API($_REQUEST['request'], $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']);
    echo $API->processAPI();
}

catch (Exception $e) {
    echo json_encode(['error' => $e->getMessage()]);
}
```

Router class

```
abstract class router {
    /* 
        Methods which seek out
        * method
        * verb
        * args

        And do authentication
    */
}
```

My main API class

```
class API extends router {
    // some generic methods specifically for this class

    // Other methods but in different files (for readability and oversight)
    use otherMethod1;
    use otherMethod2;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: What is your question?)

Comment: @VladimirKovpak ikr... basically want to extend a class multiple times while being able to inherit the parent functions and variables of an instance. If that makes any more sense -_- i don't know how to freaking explain this!

Comment: @NealVDV you should create object of your webhook class and inject it to API. You can pass it through constructor or setter method.

Comment: @TomasJavaišis That sounds like something that i'm searching for! Could you provide a very small example on how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can inject webhook class object to your API class. Small example, as requested.

```
  class Webhook { // some methods }

  class API extends router {
        private $webhook;

        public function __construct(Webhook $webhook)
        {
             $this->webhook = $webhook;
        }
        // some generic methods specifically for this class

        public function useWebhook()
        {
             $result = $this->webhook->someWebhookMethod();
             // ...
        }

        // Other methods but in different files (for readability and oversight)
        use otherMethod1;
        use otherMethod2;
        // ...
    }
```

When you can create your objects like this

```
$webhook = new Webhook();
$api = new API($webhook);

$api->useWebhook();
```

Are you looking for this?

You can read more about this approach called "dependency injection" right here: http://php-di.org/doc/understanding-di.html